# How to work with PWM in sysfs in BeagleBoneBlack correctly?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack, pwm

I want to control LED brightness with PWM with my beagleboneblack.

To enable PWM in my yocto build I've done following steps:

1. Enabled PWM in kernel menuconfig  (`bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`)
2. Patched device tree with

```
diff --git a/am335x-boneblack.dts b/am335x-boneblack.dts index e2ee8b8..8d36bfb 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts @@ -167,3 +167,21 @@       "NC",       "NC";  };
+
+&ehrpwm2 {
+    status = "okay";
+};
+
+&epwmss2 {
+    status = "okay";
+};
+
+&ehrpwm1 {
+    status = "okay";
+};
+
+&epwmss1 {
+    status = "okay";
+};
```

3. In `/sys/class/pwm`

`cd pwmchip0`

`echo 0 > export`

`cd pwm0`

`echo 200000 > period`

`echo 100000 > duty_cycle`

`echo 1 > enable`

After this I connected LED to P9_22 port and nothing works.
Also changing duty_cycle doesn't affect at anything.

[Image with debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/756k8.png) (`cat /sys/kernel/debug/pwm`)

Did I make something wrong or I've chosen wrong port ?

Thanks in Advance

Regards, Long

Comment: Just a quick shot: is pinmux correctly set?

Comment: How can i check it ? @TomasNovotny

Comment: please google for "beagleboard black pinmux", there are resources online.